# Bresenham’s Circle Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, pseudocode, bresenham, graphical-programming

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/

I was looking at Bresenham's algorithm which I'm trying to use to make a MS paint style application. I've implemented it into python and it works. However, I was not sure HOW this worked. I understood all of the algorithm except for the decision parameter. Specifically why it has to be `d = 3 – (2 * r)` , `d = d + (4*x) + 6` or `d = d + 4 * (x – y) + 10`. Is anyone familiar with the algorithm or understands the math behind how these were derived? I understood the theory behind the algorithm for lines, but I'm having a hard time understanding the circle drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just drew pixel **(x,y)**, then the next pixel to be drawn is either **(x+1,y)** or **(x+1,y-1)**

The actual condition used determine which one to choose is *appoximately* which one is closest to the ideal circle.  Specifically **(x+1,y-1)** is chosen if **(x+1)² + y² - r² > r² - (x+1)² - (y-1)²**

Collecting like terms, simplifies to **2(x+1)² + y² + (y-1)² - 2r² > 0**

Expanding gives **2x² + 2y² - 2r² + 4x - 2y  + 3 > 0**

That expression on the left is `d`.  Initially, **x=0** and **y=r**, so most of those terms are zero or cancel out and we have **d = 3 - 2y = 3 - 2r**

The other expressions you ask about indicate how `d` changes after you pick the next pixel.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+(2(x%2B2)%C2%B2+%2B+(y-1)%C2%B2+%2B+(y-2)%C2%B2+-+2r%C2%B2)+-+(2(x%2B1)%C2%B2+%2B+y%C2%B2+%2B+(y-1)%C2%B2+-+2r%C2%B2)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+(2(x%2B2)%C2%B2+%2B+y%C2%B2+%2B+(y-1)%C2%B2+-+2r%C2%B2)+-+(2(x%2B1)%C2%B2+%2B+y%C2%B2+%2B+(y-1)%C2%B2+-+2r%C2%B2)

Comment: On the second paragraph, why is it "r² - (x+1)² - (y-1)²" instead of "(x+1)² + (y-1)² - r²

Comment: It's because **(x+1,y-1)** is *inside* the circle, unlike **(x+1,y)**, which is *outside* the circle

Comment: This blog post should help you: https://funloop.org/post/2021-03-15-bresenham-circle-drawing-algorithm.html